# inherited python vars in nested tornado templates

Tags: templates, tornado

I am trying to nest tornado templates using {% include %}:

```
<html>
    {% for headline in HL['headlines'] %} 
        {% include 'hl_1.html' %}
    {% end %}
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

The template above works, and the sub-template above works. What I cannot figure out how to do is pass in the name of the sub-template (e.g.replacing 'hl_1.html' with a string parameter in the parent template's namespace). AFter reviewing the template.py source code it seems that  {% include accepts a string and nothing else. But it would be fantastic if one could dynamically specify sub-templates.

Has anyone tried this and succeeded?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

The way this is achieved usually is by using [UI modules](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/web.html?highlight=uimodule#tornado.web.UIModule).

This is how I would structure your app.

First `main.py`:

```
import tornado.ioloop                                           
import tornado.web 
import views

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):                  
    def get(self):                                              
        HL = {                                                  
                'headlines': ['head1', 'head2', 'head3'],
                }
        self.render('tmpl.html', HL=HL)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ], ui_modules=views)
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Then your template `tmpl.html`:

```
<html>
    {% for headline in HL['headlines'] %} 
        {% module Headline(headline) %}
    {% end %}
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Finally, `views.py`, where you can define all your UI modules:

```
from tornado.web import UIModule

class Headline(UIModule):
    def render(self, name):
        return '<h1>%s</h1>' % name
```

`UI modules` are like "reusable templates", that accept parameters.

Comment: I am not sure, whether I am making mistake or above thing fails with Tornado 3.1.1. They mention that ui_modules should be a dictionary, in that case it works.